# Redux Pattern in a Diagramming Scenario

Tags: typescript, redux

I have the requirement to implement a diagramming in typescript solution with some very special requirements. At the moment I am evaluating different third party libraries but I also think about a custom implementation, because I have a lot of experience with similar solutions in .NET (XAML).

What I have done in C# is to define a model with some very specific change events (ColorChanged, ShapeAdded) and a renderer that subscribes to these events. On top of it I have defined UndoRedoAction with an undo and a redo method. This works pretty well and has the advantage that the change events are very specific and can be optimized.

Some weeks ago I also had a look to the redux pattern and a I like the approach that everything is immutable and that it is very easy to implement undo/redo. The disadvantage is, that my model would be very deeply nested and that my change handler has to do a lot of dirt checks to identify the updates. For example: I have a model with multiple diagrams. Whenever I update a shape I have to create a new diagram list. In my change handler I have to loop over all diagrams and shapes to find out the update.

I have no experience with the redux pattern yet but I am really interested to get some opinions, if you think that my scenario fits to the redux pattern. Probably the answers might be based on opinions and personal preference but I am fine with it, I am looking for input.

Answer (score 0):

> I have no experience with the redux pattern yet but I am really interested to get some opinions,

With redux/immutable programming style you only change the object that needs changing. The rest can be shared.

So if `foo.bar.bas` changes, then you compare the old `foo.bar.bas` with the new `foo.bar.bas`.

## More

Here is an example function that just subscribes to *sub* portions of a state:

https://github.com/alm-tools/alm/blob/99e6c92c931f73f854470adb300d20c0db3b60db/src/app/state/simpleRedux.ts#L59-L71

If you are curious simple redux is documented here : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/alm/content/contributing/redux.html

Comment: I thought, that changes propagate to the root. Lets say, you update state.diagrams['diagramId1'].shapes['shapeId']. Then you have to change shape, therefore, the diagram, therefore the diagrams list.